# Find the length of the line segment $CE$

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let $BD$ be a median in $\triangle ABC$. The points $E,F$ trisect $BD$ such that $BE=EF=FD$. If $AB=1$ and $AF=AD$, find the length of the line segment $CE$.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $BF = DE$ and $DC = DA = AF$ and $$\angle CDE = 180-\angle ADF = 180-\angle AFD = \angle AFB $$ 
we have
$$\Delta AFB \cong \Delta EDC\; (s.a.s)$$ so $CE = AB =1$

Comment: @ChristianF-Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that $\angle AFD \cong \angle FDA$ because $m(AF) = m(DA)$ in $\triangle AFD$. Hence $\angle AFB \cong \angle EDC$ because they're complementary to congruent angles.

Also, note that $m(DA) = m(DC)$ because $BD$ is a median. Hence, $m(AF) = m(DC)$.

Now, what can you say about triangles $\triangle AFB$ and $\triangle EDC$ ?

Comment: @Amateur-I got it.